# How to stop a timer in android

Tags: android

How to stop the currently executing task of the timer.? If i use timer.cancel() it will cancel the timer but perform the currently executing task..So is there a way around so that i can cancel the currently executing task??

Answer (score 4):

Follow the cancel call with a

```
timer.purge();
```

Comment: Thanks...the timer stopped its current execution..ACtually i have a login id. The user should logout and come to login page after 3 minutes of inactivity..I have set a timer for this.. and with your answer the timer stop if there is any user interaction..So i called timer.cancel() and timer.purge() in onuserinteraction() function..But the problem is that onuserinteraction i want that the current task should be cancelled which is canceled, but the timer should be again called..If i am calling the timer function again,it is showing force close..Please help me out with it

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
   timer.cancel();
   timer.purge()
```

**purge()**  [Removes all canceled tasks from the task queue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#purge%28%29) and timer.cancel() cancels the Timer and all scheduled tasks..

---

Also take a look at [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050442/how-to-stop-immediately-the-task-scheduled-in-java-util-timer-class)

Comment: Thanks...the timer stopped its current execution..ACtually i have a login id. The user should logout and come to login page after 3 minutes of inactivity..I have set a timer for this.. and with your answer the timer stop if there is any user interaction..So i called timer.cancel() and timer.purge() in onuserinteraction() function..But the problem is that onuserinteraction i want that the current task should  be cancelled which is canceled, but the timer should be again called..If i am calling the timer function again,it is showing force close..Please help me out with it

Comment: do you have a solution for my problem..if so please give...it will be really helpful of u

Comment: so can u tell me how to reset the timer instead of cancelling it ...so that i can use it again and again??

Comment: Just create a new timer every time you need it. You can't reuse one Timer after cancelling it as I said before. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976022/setting-a-timer-for-a-timeout-new-timer-fails-after-cancel-and-purge) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866349/resched-timer-after-cancel-gives-java-lang-illegalstateexception-timer-cancel). BTW why don't you accept the answer to this question @AnshulJain ??